# Membership and linking user to custom table

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Basically I'd like to use default .Net membership since I don't need anything special out of user as a whole, but what I need is to connect user to a sort of log/history table, is it as simple as making a foreign key out of user id in that table? Or is there a more complicated trick to it?

I would additionally like to create a view model with some user data like `ID`, `UserName` etc..(similar to `RegisterModel`) but that I'd use for that log/history inside the application. It looks to me that it's possible but something is bugging me...

So, possible or not?

**Update**

```
UserModel                             LogModel
public Guid ID {get; set;}            public int ID {get; set;}
public string UserName {get; set;}    public string ActionTaken {get; set;}
public string Email {get; set;}       public Guid UserID {get; set;}
                                      public virtual UserModel User {get; set;}
```

It might be useful to note, I'm doing database first, and using `DbContext` EF tool for starting code generation, and afterwards I ofc add what I deem necessary.

My first opinion is that I'm missing some mapping or something similar...

Comment: Sure it's possible. What have you tried and what difficulties did you encounter that you would like to ask about?

Comment: Well, first of all, it didn't work as i described it here. The view model I made didn't "connect" to the user the way I expected it. Since I made simple `UserModel` with some basic data as described, and I've added the foreign key to the `Log` table, when attempted saving I had to directly inject the UserID. Instead that it recognizes it from the model i obviously made falsely...

Comment: Any code you would like to share?

Comment: I was just about to edit my question to add models I've made. And how it went.